# Use of "respectively" in "both these localities are on the banks, respectively, at 12 km and 20 km upstream"

Tags: word-usage, adverbs, word-order

> Both these source localities are on the banks of the Rhine, respectively, at 12 km and 20 km upstream from Bonn.

In the above sentence, is *respectively* needed, and if so, is it properly used?

Comment: Since you haven't *named* them, it's not appropriate to use "respectively" to link the sequence of the two distances upstream to that of the two sources.

Comment: Presuming they *are* named in a (hopefully *the*) preceding sentence, then yes, it's properly used, and reduces the ambiguity of *which* locality is located *where* on the Rhine.

Comment: Given the topic, I have a suspicion that the sentence was written by a German native speaker, and respectively is a translation of "beziehungsweise" that has been placed incorrectly.

Comment: But do you use _at_ with _upstream from_ something? Don't you use _by_? As in _...on the banks of the Rhine, upstream from Bonn, by 12 and 20 km respectively._ If you use at I feel like using _of Bonn_. Not a native speaker here. I find _respectively_ before focuses on the list whereas after focuses on ordering/matching the list to preceding references. Again, not a native speaker here.

Comment: @Amphiteóth, while *by...from* works in your example, it seems more natural to me to say either of *at 12 km and 20 km, respectively, upstream of Bonn* or *at 12 km and 20 km upstream of Bonn, respectively*.  When the  *upstream* phrase precedes the *12 and 20 km* phrase, either your *by...from* construction or the following might be used:  “...on the banks of the Rhine, upstream of Bonn 12 and 20 km respectively”.

Comment: @jwpat7 Thank you that is very insightful. I also note in both cases you use _of_ Bonn indeed, and not _from_.

Answer (score 2):

In the question as it stands, out of context, there is some merit to  FumbleFingers' comment “it's not appropriate to use "respectively" to link the sequence of the two distances upstream to that of the two [unnamed] sources”.  However, as you may observe in answers and comments at [ELU question 34843](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/34843), some sentences use *respectively* to indicate that things are separate.  The need to so indicate does not depend on whether things are named.  For example, consider the following two sentences about two treasures.

> Treasures X and Y are on the banks of the Rhine, at 12 km and 20 km, respectively, upstream of Bonn.
>   Treasures X and Y are on the banks of the Rhine, at 12 km and 20 km upstream of Bonn.

The first form explicitly places one treasure 12 km upstream and the other 20 km upstream.  The second form is ambiguous, if we suppose parts of a treasure may be at multiple locations.  The same cases apply if  “Treasures X and Y” is replaced by “The treasures”, without names.

The location of *respectively* in the sentence in the question is awkward and the comma after it does not help.  Lots of readers would expect the list to precede *respectively*, and will be briefly taken aback by the awkward location of it in the example sentence.  You can find more answers about locating *respectively* before a list in [ELU question 197570](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/197570).